# Merging 2 tables with complete

Tags: mysql

Let say that I have the 2 following tables

```
id| price            id| qty
1 | 1000             1 | 0.5
2 | 1020             3 | 1
3 | 1040             6 | 1.5
4 | 1050
5 | 1070
6 | 1090
```

And for the result I want to use the last available qty to compute each value

```
id| price| qty | value (qty * price)
1 | 1000 | 0.5 | 500
2 | 1020 | 0.5 | 510         
3 | 1040 | 1   | 1040    
4 | 1050 | 1   | 1050
5 | 1070 | 1   | 1070
6 | 1090 | 1.5 | 1635
```

I can't find a way to do that. Can you help ?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of using a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) however you will not get the exact result that you are looking for because you do not have a complete set of values in your second table for the items..

```
SELECT id, price, qty, qty*price as value from qtys LEFT JOIN prices on id
```

An INNER JOIN would do just as well.

```
SELECT id, price, qty, qty*price as value from qtys INNER JOIN prices on id
```

This will produce something like this:

```
id| price| qty | value (qty * price)
1 | 1000 | 0.5 | 500        
3 | 1040 | 1   | 1040    
6 | 1090 | 1.5 | 1635
```

it's not possible for join on ids 2, 4 and 5. In order to produce the exact output you will have to intrapolate some values for the qty for the missing items. However, you seem to expect 0.5 for some of the missing values and 1.0 for the other.

> An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables,
>   based on a common field between them.
>
> The most common type of join is: SQL INNER JOIN (simple join). An SQL
>   INNER JOIN returns all rows from multiple tables where the join
>   condition is met.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I understand the answer but not the upvote.   The first query will return a bunch of `NULL` values.  The second will return 3 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oops, fastest gun in the west response on my part :( hope the edit salvages it, but will happily delete the answer if you think it's worthy of deletion.

Comment: . . No, the edit does not improve the answer, as far as the OP's question is oncerned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to look up the `qty` value, then an aggregation:

```
select id, price, qty, qty * price as value
from (select t1.*,
             (select t2.qty
              from t2
              where t2.id <= t1.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as qty
      from t1
     ) t;
```